# Java - Вывод BigDecimal в удобном виде

Tags: java, bigdecimal

Помогите разобраться, мне нужно, чтобы BigDecimal выводился на экран в зависимости от величины числа (разрядности) в нормальном виде или в экспоненциальном. Например числа длиной до 8 символов должны выглядеть так: "12345678", а свыше так: "1,2345Е+9". 
Методы:

```
toPlainString();
toEngineeringString();
toString();
```

работают не так, как ожидается.

```
public class TestBigDecimalOutput {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        BigDecimal d = new BigDecimal("57657657657453646587980887663654676580.24545346565476767645");
        String outPlainString = d.toPlainString();
        String outEngineeringString = d.toEngineeringString();
        String outString = d.toString();

        System.out.println(outPlainString);
        System.out.println(outEngineeringString);
        System.out.println(outString);
    }
}
```

Код выше выводит следующие строки:

```
57657657657453646587980887663654676580.24545346565476767645
57657657657453646587980887663654676580.24545346565476767645
57657657657453646587980887663654676580.24545346565476767645
```

Подскажите, что я делаю не так?

---

Путем эксперимента было обнаружено, что если создавать BigDecimal через  `BigDecimald = BigDecimal.valueOf(57657657657453646587980887663654676580.24545346565476767645);`
то логика вывода будет ближе к тому, что требуется получить:

57657657657453650000000000000000000000
57.65765765745365E+36
5.765765765745365E+37

Но нужно принимать аргументом именно строку, т.к. Double не проходит по размеру.
Подскажите, как решить эту задачу?

Answer (score 1):

вам надо установить точность (precision) и округлять до нее

```
jshell> new BigDecimal("12345678").round(new MathContext(8, RoundingMode.HALF_UP)).toEngineeringString()
$21 ==> "12345678"

jshell> new BigDecimal("57657657657453646587980887663654676580.24545346565476767645").round(new MathContext(8, RoundingMode.HALF_UP)).toEngineeringString()
$22 ==> "57.657658E+36"
```

если надо именно обрезать (а не округлять), то используйте другой режим округления: `RoundingMode.DOWN`